# I don't understand why it is having this error. Even if the directory is correct and also the filename

Tags: javascript, react-native

[IMAGE OF THE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YZio.png)

Android Bundling failed 5334ms

Unable to resolve module ../model/weights.bin from
D:\Repos\BANANAFILE\helpers\tensor-helper.js:

None of these files exist:

- model\weights.bin(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
- model\weights.bin\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)

10 |

11 | const modelJson = require('../model/model.json');

> 12 | const modelWeights = require('../model/weights.bin');

Answer (score 0):

React-native uses es6 imports so do this instead

```js
import modelJson from "../model/model.json"
import modelWeights from "../model/weights.bin"
```

Comment: I tried it but still the same error ... 


None of these files exist:
  * model\weights.bin(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  * model\weights.bin\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  3 | import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
  4 | import modelJson from "../model/model.json"
> 5 | import modelWeights from "../model/weights.bin"